# Prove similarity of triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

[image: Diagram]

> I found this question in one of my textbooks.

In the given figure, ABCD and AEFG are 2 squares. 
Prove that:

$i) \frac{AF}{AG} = \frac{AC}{AD}$

$ii) ∆ACF \sim ∆ADG$

> This is what I could do:

$i) AF^2 = AG^2 + GF^2\\
\rightarrow AF^2 = 2•AG^2
\rightarrow AF = AG•\sqrt{2}
\rightarrow \frac{AF}{AG} = \sqrt{2}$

Similarly, $\frac{AC}{AD} = \sqrt{2}$

Therefore, $$\frac{AF}{AG} = \frac{AC}{AD}$$

> In $(ii)$ part, $\frac{AF}{AG} = \frac{AC}{AD}$ can be one reason for similarity. What will be the other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason 1 - $$\frac{AF}{AG} = \frac{AC}{AD}$$
Reason 2 -  $\angle DAC = \angle GAF = 45°$
$\rightarrow \angle DAC - \angle GAC = \angle GAF - \angle GAC $
$$ \rightarrow \angle DAG = \angle CAF$$

> $\therefore$ By $Side-Angle-Side$ congruency,

$$ \triangle ACF \sim \triangle ADG $$

Answer (score 1):

Since a [spiral similarity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpiralSimilarity.html) centred at $A$ maps $GF$ to $DC$, so there's also a spiral similarity (see for lemma #3 of [this](http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad/geolemmas.pdf) for a sketch of proof ) centred at $A$ mapping $GD$ to $FC$, hence QED.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But actually, I would prefer something a bit easy as I can't make head or tail out of terms like 'spiral similarity','mapping' and 'lemma'. Something comprehensible to a 14-year old would help.

Comment: FYI I'm 16 year old, and I would **highly** recommend working on the book "Eucledian Geometry in Mathematical Olympiad" by Evan Chen if you're interested in geo. Also, which part you didn't understand ? (Spiral similarity basically means what you see in the image, a composition of a rotation and a dilation, both centred at same point; mapping just a fancy term for a transformation; and lemma basically means a part of a proof)

Comment: What does dilation mean? BTW, this image will give you an idea of my level of understanding. This is my textbook's pic - https://photos.app.goo.gl/jh6WxUYrCTjutIwx2

Comment: Sorry - then when I have free time I'll write a detailed and elementary explanation of what I wrote.

Comment: When you're free, come [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73654/explaining-spiral-similarity-to-aditya) and give me a @ping.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Delta ADG$ and increase it at $\sqrt2$ such that you'll get $\Delta AD'G'$ with $D\in AD'$ and $G\in AG'.$

Now, rotate $\Delta AD'G'$ around $A$ on $45^{\circ}$.

You'll get $D'\rightarrow C$ and $G'\rightarrow F$ and we are done!

Maybe it will help to understand the Alex's reasoning.